# How can I display an random quote from an Javascript Array in html?

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to make random quotes that are listed in an array appear on my website on reload however I cant quite get it to work

Javascript:

```
function textOfToday() {
    
    var textOfTodayArray = [
        'String 1', 'String 2'
    ]

document.getElementById('randomTitle').value = textOfTodayArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*textOfTodayArray.length)];
}
```

The following html div code is designed to display the text however I just cant get it:

```
<div class="randomTitle" style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

Ive also tried using `id="randomTitle"` in the div part but this did not work either

Is there something else wrong maybe? Im not no expert by all means but I cant spot any syntax mistakes

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So is there any errors in your developer console? My guess there is one.

Comment: well `getElementById` would not access an element that has no id. Divs do not have value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `innerHTML` property to display in the HTML element. Also make use of the id tag when you are targeting by Id. Also, You never invoked your function so it never ran.

```js
function textOfToday() {

  var textOfTodayArray = ['String 1', 'String 2'];

  document.getElementById('randomTitle').innerHTML = textOfTodayArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * textOfTodayArray.length)];
}

textOfToday();
```

```html
<div id="randomTitle" style="text-align: center;">Hi</div>
```

Comment: Hello there! I already posted an answer that explains everything, plus I added references, so I don't think the author of the question need this answer.

Comment: @NNL993 I think you did but you didn't explain everything wrong with it. Also, SO is a free space and I am free to post my answer. I didn't realise you had posted your answer must be seconds before. It can be removed by upvotes if its not ok. The way I approach SO is I learn from other answers and will suggest you do the same instead of asking people to delete there post

Comment: Thanks for answer! Just trying to keep clean Stack Overflow, just I didn't find your answer useful because there was @diemondtank's answer, he explained some details that I missed, so our two answers perfectly explains everything that author of question needs.

Comment: @NNL993 Thanks for the concern! Just want to point out Its better to take a minute and write full answer that answers everything rather than posting incomplete answers as you mentioned. This doesn't mean my answer here is necessarily better. Additionally, you can read the guidelines for more info https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: thank you all very very much it works just as expected may god bless you all!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call the function in your js `textOfToday()`. You are defining it, but never calling.

Also, yes, you need to change the `class` to `id` if you are going to use `getElementById`.

Lastly, you need to set `innerText` instead of `value`

Answer (score 0):

[`document.querySelector('.foo').value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDataElement/value) mostly using for [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/HTML5_input_types),
to display information in the div or whatever element is it, you better use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
function textOfToday() {

var textOfTodayArray = [
    'String 1', 'String 2'
]

document.getElementById('randomTitle').innerText = textOfTodayArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*textOfTodayArray.length)];
}

textOfToday()
```

```html
<div id="randomTitle" style="text-align: center;"></div>
```